# accessing userControl value in winform c# using Model

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm working in a smal project where I'm using userControl displayed within the main form. I'm using a Model class which allow access to database look like:

```
    public void InsertRoute(Route route)
    {
        string routecode = route.RouteCode.ToString();
        string vehiclecode = route.VehicleCode.ToString();
        string firsstudentname = route.FirstStudentName.ToString();


        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertRoute2", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RouteCode", routecode));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VehicleCode", vehiclecode));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstStudentName", firsstudentname));


            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

then i have a user control called UCCreateRotue which has several textboxes and  Button click Event handler :

```
   private void btnCreateRoute_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UCRouteCreate form = new UCRouteCreate();
        //DialogResult dialog = form.ShowDialog();

        //if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
        //{
            Route route = controller.CreateMovieFromText(form);
            controller.InsertRoute(route);
            //RefreshTable();
        //}

    }
```

then i have a Class called route as follow

```
       class Route
{

    private   GlobalReach.UserControls.UCRouteCreate usrCon;
    public string RouteCode
    {
        get { return usrCon.txtRouteCode.Text ;}
        set { usrCon.txtRouteCode.Text = value ; }

    }
```

}

then i have a method in controller as follow to perform the insert which is done through sproc

```
        public Route CreateRouteFromText(UCRouteCreate form)
    {

        string routecode =form.txtRouteCode.Text.ToString();
        string vehiclecode = form.txtVehicleCode.Text.ToString();
        string firststudentname = form.txtFStudent.Text.ToString();


        Route route = new Route();
        return route;
    }
```

my problem is when i click on the button click the code is working as i do have new rows inserted into my table but with empty value i.e the values are entered as nothing (if that make any sense) and the field that i dd not choose to fill entered as NULL value..?
could you please advise on why when i enter values in my usrControl TextBox the value is not captured through my code..
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

button click event creates an empty form, you've commented out the show dialog lines, so the inputs will still be empty (unless you have them initialize to anything, but even then).  In CreateRouteFromText, you assign the form values to local variables, and then create an empty Route object and pass that back to the insert method. so no surprise that you have empty rows.

should at least set the Route objects to what the form has:

```
public Route CreateRouteFromText(UCRouteCreate form)
{
    return new Route() 
    { 
        RouteCode = form.txtRouteCode.Text,
        VehicleCode = form.txtVehicleCode.Text,
        FirstStudentName = form.txtFStudent.Text
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi rangarok56 i commented the showdialog as it seems not to work in a user control as my user control are not showing within a form!